# How to change the directory rsyslogd uses?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, configuration, rsyslog

I'm running an ubuntu instance and have limited space on the drive mounted on the / directory so I want to change where rsyslogd logs from /var/log to another directory, say /abc. I've tried changing the /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf file to set the directories to /abc and restarted the rsyslogd process.

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /abc/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/abc/syslog
kern.*                          -/abc/kern.log
mail.*                          -/abc/mail.log
```

Despite the changed the logs are still going to /var/log. Can some tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was a simple permissions issue with the directory. I did not give the group write privileges.